# OPen a modal form to display a data table and then receive the results when the form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataTable which was build within a method that I would like to offer the user the oppertunity to change some data on.

My plan (in English) is to:-

1. Create the form with the right look and feel, will have a dataGridView and Button on there.  Grid view has columns to match the DataTable and the button closes the form.
2. within the method I will do a myForm test = new MyForm(); and then a test.showDialog();

up to here I am ok.. I think..  What I can't seem to work out is how I can 'send' the datatable to the form to be bound to the dataGridView and then collect the altered table back into the origonal (or another) dataTable...

Hope that's clear, Thanks

p.s. - Still learning so please don't assume that I will know any shorthand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass that information through your own constructor.  On the modal form, it would look like this:

```
public Form2(DataTable dt) {
  InitializeComponent();
  dgv.DataSource = dt;
}
```

To show your form:

```
using (Form2 f2 = new Form2(myDataTable)) {
  f2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I then get the changes back from the form on close so that my method continues from where it was when the form laoded?

Comment: @user3570798 In this example, myDataTable will have those changes since it's a reference object.